# Web Driver: How to know current frame activeness?

Tags: javascript, webdriver

I'm having 15 frames in a page where I need to move in and out,

How I can I come to know under which frame i'm in?

e.g From frame1 to frame8 and frame8 to frame12 and so on...

Comment: by frame do you mean iframe or div?

Comment: You can't know which iframe has the focus, and relay that to another iframe. You could potentially track the mouse position based on activity in a frame and associate it with a keyvalue used to load the URL from the master page, but that's terribly convoluted. Whats your intent?

Comment: wd.switchTo().defaultContent();
//Switching to Sub frame
wd.switchTo().frame("canvas_frame");
One frame's out put is an input of another one and so on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WebDriver, you explicitly have to switch into a frame or iframe via `driver.switchTo().frame()` (or its equivalent in whatever language binding you're using). As such, you should always **know** which frame or iframe you're in, because you switched to it. If you find you need to keep track of it for some reason, you might try something like adding an object to a list every time you switch to a frame or iframe. You can't switch to a parent or sibling frame in WebDriver, so to navigate to one of those, you'll need use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`, which will always switch to the top-level frame, and navigate down the hierarchy again.

Comment: You *can* (now) switch to a parent frame: driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame() (Selenium.NET v2.53).

Comment: Calling `switchTo().defaultContent()` before navigating into the target iframe is a simple, predictable way to ensure that you know what context you're running in, especially in instances where you're jumping in and out of iframes and windows within test cases. Simple and sufficient.